# Java -Struts 1.2 combobox question

Tags: java, struts

I am using java (Struts 1.2). My first page is a login page. After a successful login, the second page is displayed The second page contains a form in which one of the fields is a combo box. I want this combo box should be filled so that the user can select the option.

I have tried many methods, like using html:option collections, and html:optionsCollections etc. but it is showing errors like bean not found.

Can any body give me a sample working code.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the values to fill the combobox? The database? A literal list?

Comment: Have you tried Google? In order to help you, I will need to see what logic goes to from login to display (and which actions are called).

Comment: I already tried google and used the suggested solutions but unable to solve the problem.

Comment: What's inside your literal list?

Comment: literal list contains few strings which i want to use to populate the combo box

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
List< LabelValueBean> hourList = new ArrayList<LabelValueBean>();
pageContext.setAttribute("hourList", hourList);
%>

<html:select property="endhour">
    <html:options collection="hourList" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
<html:select>
```

The property on html:select is the one in your form which will be filled when the user selects something from the combobox.

--- sorry couldn't format it to show the code clearly

Comment: Where I have to write this code in action class of login form (previous page) or action class of the jsp page in which the combo box will be displayed. I tried by writing code in action class of previous page but when I am using the attribute say hourList in the next page it is showing error like bean not found

Comment: the code should be written in your JSP. if you look at this, you can see that its a scriptlet. The hourList(ArrayList Object) needs to come from your bean maybe from your session or use the code above and populate the hourList. Regardless of the first page( like you said the login page ), you need to populate your beans to prepare for the next page.

Answer (score 0):

The use of html tag required to be in html:form and that both must have an associated bean, you configure it in struts.xml.

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="LoginForm"
        type="struts.forms.LoginForm" />
</form-beans>

<action  name="LoginForm" path="/logon" type="common.Logon"
        parameter="cmd">
        <forward name="error" path="/html/login/login.jsp?login_error=1" />
        <forward name="success" path="/login.do" />            
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell you is this:

- Once you successfully login (through your `LoginAction` in this example), let your action forward to another action which will populate your list.
- Populate your list and save it in the request (like so, `request.setAttribute("contents", list)`. Now forward your page to a JSP file.
- On the JSP file, you will have to read your `contents` (as stored in `request.setAttribute` method) and do something of this effect:

Example:

```
<html:select property="selectedValue">
    <html:options name="contents" />
</html:select>
```

More information on Struts [**HTML**](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/tld-summary.html) TagLib.